# Using a class from a .jar file

Tags: java, file-io, jar

I am trying to use a class `FileUtils.class` from a `commons-io-2.4.jar` file. The code is as follows:-

```
package Lynda.Essential_training;
import java.io.*;
//import Lynda.Essential_training.org.apache.commons.io.*;

public class fileHandlingCommons
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        File f1 = new File("/home/kusur/java_programs/source.txt");
        File f2 = new File("target2.txt");

        FileUtils.copyFile(f1,f2);
    }
}
```

When I compile this program, with the command:-

```
javac -cp /usr/sys/java_programs/Lynda/Essential_training/Commons-io-2.4.jar Lynda/Essential_training/fileHandlingCommons.java
```

I get the following error:-

```
Lynda/Essential_training/fileHandlingCommons.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        FileUtils.copyFile(f1,f2);
        ^
  symbol:   variable FileUtils
  location: class fileHandlingCommons
```

I am getting the same error when I am extracting all the files from the `.jar` folder and then compiling the program (in which case, the commented import statement in the program is used).

Can you please help?

Comment: Have you tried `import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`? Location of package is not included to the import path, it is derived from inside the jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your import statement containing `FileUtils` is commented out (`org.apache.commons.io.*`).. uncomment it, recompile and try again:

```
package Lynda.Essential_training;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.*; //<-- the problem

public class fileHandlingCommons
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        File f1 = new File("/home/kusur/java_programs/source.txt");
        File f2 = new File("target2.txt");

        FileUtils.copyFile(f1,f2);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is still there. Even when I have added the `FileUtils.class` to the package name. The error says that `package org.apache.commons.io does not exist`

Comment: is the commons-io.jar file in the classpath location you are indicating?

Comment: yes, I am giving the .jar file in the classpath as well. But is it necessary when I have extracted the entire folder?

Comment: You unzipped the jar file?  This will cause a few problems around the package name matching the folder structure, if you didn't match it up properly.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I assume, FileUtils is under some package that you have not imported in your code.

Can you import that specific class and compile?